# How to use EditText value (numberDecimal) in math operations Java

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext, double

I have a EditText view :

```
  <EditText
            android:id="@+id/vorgabezeit"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#0277BD"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="5"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
```

The value entered in this EditText I would like to use it in an math operation.
Before I had fixed values :

```
public void submitOrder(View view) {
     displayPrice((procente / myEditNum) * mitarbeiter);
}
```

where variables were defined as :

```
int procente = 120;
int mitarbeiter = 1;
```

Now, I searched for hours on the web how to take that value entered in EditText and use id further, and this is as close as I got :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int procente = 120;
    int mitarbeiter = 1;
    EditText myEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.vorgabezeit);
    String myEditValue = myEdit.getText().toString();
    double myEditNum = Double.parseDouble(myEditValue);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void submitOrder(View view) {
        displayPrice((procente / myEditNum) * mitarbeiter);
    }
}
```

The application crashes from the start.
Thank you for your patience and help.

Best regards,
Robert

Comment: post the error please?

Comment: Hello
    08-18 19:42:19.335 27248-27248/com.example.android.prmienrechner V/SettingsInterface: invalidate [system]: current 494 != cached 0
    08-18 19:42:19.337 27248-27248/com.example.android.prmienrechner D/ActivityThread: hoder:android.app.IActivityManager$ContentProviderHolder@299cbcf1,provider,holder.Provider:android.content.ContentProviderProxy@cb410d6

I guess this is what you are refering. Sorry for the delay but I took a nap since I'll be going to work in about an hour ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you add android:inputType="number" to your EditText on the xml to ensure the user can ONLY type numbers on it, then :

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        findViewById(R.id.button)
                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        displayPrice((procente / Double.parseDouble(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.vorgabezeit))
                                .getText().toString())) * mitarbeiter);
                    }
                });
    }
```

btw your code crashes because you called findviewById before setting the content view to the activity so basically it searches on a non-existing layout and your edit text and button become null because of it

Comment: Hello. Thank you ! It works, finally :D . I just had to // some of the old code and erase the last } from yours so that includes the other lines too. Thank you again. Now I'll have to study it to see how it works. Java code is killing me. Is way harder than anything I'm used to :) . Strange is that for some reason, after running the app on my phone, Android Studio stops responding ...

Comment: P.S. any advice on where can I learn very, very BASIC Java ?! My best option would be a place to start as if I never saw code before, because it's the only way to be sure that I don't skip something basic/important that I will need on the way ...

Answer (score 1):

**First** you need to post the LogCat when you are having a crash.

**Second** You can not call `findViewById` until after `setContentView` is called. You should to initialize your edit text in onCreate.

```
// Initialize values in onCreate after setContentView
EditText myEdit;
String myEditValue;
double myEditNum;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.vorgabezeit);
    myEditValue = myEdit.getText().toString();
    myEditNum = Double.parseDouble(myEditValue);
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your time and answer, but the answer from Juan Hurtado was the last one, seemed more accurate, I tested it and it works (with some small tweaks). Next time I'll know to post the LogCat content when I encounter an error ! Thank you again for the effort !!!

Answer (score 0):

What about `getText()`. I added button, since you have to get text after some user action, not right after `onCreate` event.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.vorgabezeit);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Log.v("EditText", mEdit.getText().toString());
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your time and answer, but the answer from Juan Hurtado was the last one, seemd more accurate, I tested it and it works (with some small tweaks). Thannk you again for the effort !!!